# how to convert column into row in perl

Tags: perl

I am reading values from my sql database for a column. Now I want to convert columns values in row in comma(ex:-"abc","xyz")

```
Source Data:-
amol
aakash
shami
krishna

Output expected: ( "amol","aakash","shami","krishna")
```

Code which I am trying:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

 $t = `date`;
 #print $t;
 $GCMS_SERVER = $ENV{DSQUERY};
 $GCMS_USERNAME = $ENV{GCMS_USERNAME};
 $GCMS_PASSWORD = $ENV{GCMS_PASSWORD};
 $GCMS_DATABASE = $ENV{GCMS_DATABASE};

 #print "test\n";
 my $query = "SELECT Label FROM FeedGenSource WHERE BaseFileName ='aldgctna'";
 #print "SQL =$query\n";

 my $sqlcmd = (qq/
     set nocount on
     go
     use $GCMS_DATABASE
     go
     $query
     /);

   open(::DBCMD, "sqsh -S$GCMS_SERVER -U$GCMS_USERNAME -h -w100 -P-  <<EOF
 $GCMS_PASSWORD
 $sqlcmd
 go
 EOF
     |") || die("Could not communicate with DB ");

 while(<::DBCMD>){
 print "$_";
 }

 #print "done\n";
 close ::DBCMD;
 exit
```

This is the perl script. I want to use output in query as in statement.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Is the goal to change the database format? Is the goal to make an output?

Answer (score 2):

Your output comes from this section of your code:

```
while(<::DBCMD>){
  print "$_";
}
```

The filehandle `::DBCMD` is connected to the output from your `sqsh` command. Your code reads each record from that filehandle and prints it to `STDOUT`.

If you want to do something cleverer with the output, then you're going to have to store the data in some kind of data structure (probably an array in this case) and manipulate that.

I expect you want something like this:

```
my @data;

while (<::DBCMD>) {
  chomp; # remove the newline
  push @data, $_;
}

# And then:
print join(',', @data), "\n";
```

To print the exact output that you ask for, you would need this:

```
print '(', join(',', map { qq["$_"] } @data), ")\n";
```

But I have to ask... why are you making your life so difficult by manipulating data that comes back from `sqsh`? You should really look at Perl's database interface library, [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). That will make your life far simpler.

A few other tips:

- Always have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code. And fix the issues they will reveal.
- Use Perl's built-in date and time tools instead of shelling out to `date`.
- Using `::` on your bareword filehandle achieves nothing. Just `DBCMD` works the same way and is less confusing.